# Google Colab Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.0.5 but source was compiled with: 8.1.0

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection, object-detection-api, cudnn

While training with Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API in Google Collab, I get the following errors:

```
2022-03-07 15:27:51.475298: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:359] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.0.5 but source was compiled with: 8.1.0.  CuDNN library needs to have matching major version and equal or higher minor version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
2022-03-07 15:27:51.477142: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops.cc:1120 : UNKNOWN: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
```

I have tried updating my CuDNN library in Google collab, using this StackOverflow answer:
[Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.0.5 but source was compiled with: 8.1.0. when using google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70091951/loaded-runtime-cudnn-library-8-0-5-but-source-was-compiled-with-8-1-0-when-us).
However, this does not solve the issue.

I am using Tensorflow 2.7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a workaround for the problem, as posted on the official [Github](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2600)

This may not work always and may not be safe, but as a workaround for the time being, you may try running `!apt install --allow-change-held-packages libcudnn8=8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2`