# Azure VM Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.2.4 but source was compiled with: 8.6.0

Tags: azure, keras, jupyter-notebook, virtual-machine, cudnn

I have tried to fit a Keras model on a notebook in Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio GPU machine. I have received an error similar to what was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71383636/google-colab-loaded-runtime-cudnn-library-8-0-5-but-source-was-compiled-with-8):

```
2023-04-27 09:56:21.098249: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:417] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.2.4 but source was compiled with: 8.6.0.  CuDNN library needs to have matching major version and equal or higher minor version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
2023-04-27 09:56:21.099011: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at pooling_ops_common.cc:412 : UNIMPLEMENTED: DNN library is not found.
2023-04-27 09:56:21.099050: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): UNIMPLEMENTED: DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node model_2/max_pooling1d_6/MaxPool}}]]
2023-04-27 09:56:21.100704: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:417] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.2.4 but source was compiled with: 8.6.0.  CuDNN library needs to have matching major version and equal or higher minor version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
2023-04-27 09:56:21.101366: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at pooling_ops_common.cc:412 : UNIMPLEMENTED: DNN library is not found.
```

What is the solution for Azures' machines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a royal pain in the arse to fix - I don't know why Microsoft haven't fixed/bumped the cuDNN version from 6.1. The included conda environment with tensorflow doesn't work.

Essentially, we need to manually install an older version of tensorflow, or a newer version of cuDNN. As no version of tensorflow is compatable with cuDNN 6.1 we are forced to upgrade cuDNN.

The solution that works is as follows:

1. At time of writing - you want cuDNN version 6.8 (for TF 1.12.x) - get cuDNN link from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive) with your client computer, but stop the link so you can get one with an auth key

[image: From nVidia website]
[image]

2. Enter the link into the `export URL` line below
3. Copy and paste this into your running compute terminal
4. Wait 5 minutes ☕️

```bash
export URL="PASTE-LINK-HERE"
# ==== DOWNLOAD CUDDN ==== 
curl $URL -o ./cudnn-linux-x86_64-8.6.0.163_cuda11-archive.tar.xz 
sudo tar -xvf ./cudnn-linux-x86_64-8.6.0.163_cuda11-archive.tar.xz
# ==== INSTALL CUDDN ==== 
sudo cp ./cudnn-*-archive/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/include 
sudo cp -P ./cudnn-*-archive/lib/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64 
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
# ==== CONFIGURE DYNAMIC RUNTIME BINDINGS ==== 
sudo ldconfig
# ==== INSTALL CONDA ENV ==== 
conda create -n "tfgpu" python=3.10 -y
conda activate tfgpu
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.8.0 ipykernel -y
python3 -m pip install nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.6.0.163 tensorflow==2.12.*
mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d
echo 'CUDNN_PATH=$(dirname $(python -c "import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.__file__)"))' >> $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/:$CUDNN_PATH/lib' >> $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
source $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name tfgpu --display-name "Python (tf-cudnn8.6)"
# ==== VERIFY ==== 
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

Testing this on the [tensorflow mnist example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner):

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you think that the suggestion below works too? it seems to be simpler...

Comment: I'll give it a go and let you know; I don't expect it to work as I tried something similar but may be wrong. Does it work for you?

Comment: He said that it worked but it seems to him that the GPU does not provide the expected performance. Now since I expect the GPU make things faster I am not sure it all works the same with our method and his

Comment: So I can confirm your friend's solution does work ~ and it does look like it hits the GPU; however you're then stuck with tensorflow version `2.4.1` (which is from Jan 2021 - maybe why not as performant?) - and you will need to do what I did at some point if you ever want to upgrade tensorflow to a more modern version.

Comment: pardon my English, "hits the GPU"?

Comment: Sorry - uses the GPU!

Answer (score 0):

In any notebook, you run:

```
!conda create -n cuda_env python=3.8 numpy scipy pandas scikit-learn matplotlib jupyter ipykernel cudatoolkit=10.1 -c anaconda -y
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1
!pip install keras==2.4.3
!python -m ipykernel install --user --name cuda_env --display-name "Python (CUDA)"
```

This creates a kernel named Python (CUDA) you can later choose.